# Google maps (v2) activity not appearing menu

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an activity in my project which using google maps to show current location I want to show menu on top like in other activities.
The map and location appears and working well, but the menu never shows up for some reason.

I am extending my class with `AppCompatActivity`

This is my activity where I am using `getSupportActionBar`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylocation_activity);

    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // finish the activity
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Layout mylocation_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.damian.currentlocation.activity.MyLocationActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```